# why jdb won't recognize the "Integer" class?

Tags: java, jdb

I connect like this:

```
$ jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:hostname=x.x.x.x,port=8008
```

In the jdb prompt I do this:

```
> stop in com.me.some.Gizmo.function
```

Then it breaks correctly, but when I do this:

```
> print Integer.parseInt("4")
```

It outputs this:

```
com.sun.tools.example.debug.expr.ParseException: Name unknown: java.lang.Integer
```

Why on earth can't jdb recognize the "Integer" class??

Comment: Instead of using jdb on the command line, can you use the Debug button in your IDE for remote debugging.  You should find it *much* easier.

Comment: Good question. I can reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Although java allows classes from the package `java.lang` to be referenced without the fully qualified name, JDB does not.

```
> print java.lang.Integer.parseInt("4")
```

should work.