# JDB Map Lookup With Integer

Tags: java, dictionary, jdb

I'm debugging some code that uses `Map<Integer,...>`, but I'm having great difficulty finding the values associated with various `Integer`s! Here's a minimum working example:

java code (saved to `.\src`):

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        Map<Integer,String> mymap = new HashMap<Integer,String>(2);
        mymap.put(new Integer(5), "five");
        mymap.put(6, "six");
    }
}
```

Terminal 1 (powershell):

```
javac -g $(ls . *.java -r -name)
java -cp src -Xdebug '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,server=y,suspend=y,address=hey' Hello
```

Terminal 2 (powershell):

```
jdb -attach hey
```

...

```
VM Started: No frames on the current call stack

main[1] stop at Hello:10
Deferring breakpoint Hello:10.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
main[1] cont
> Set deferred breakpoint Hello:10

Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", Hello.main(), line=10 bci=40

main[1] dump mymap.get(5)
com.sun.jdi.InvalidTypeException: Can't assign primitive value to object
 mymap.get(5) = null
main[1] dump mymap.get(new Integer(5))
com.sun.tools.example.debug.expr.ParseException: No class named: Integer
 mymap.get(new Integer(5)) = null
main[1]
```

How should I go about looking up a value from a `Map<Integer,?>`?

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130892/why-jdb-wont-recognize-the-integer-class?rq=1

Comment: +1 This is an exact duplicate

Comment: @AaronDigulla For what it's worth, I'm willing to take a work-around. He's wanting to find the `Integer` class; I don't care about that class, but I want to look up from my map in any way possible.

Comment: Your problem isn't the map, it's `Integer`. If you want to figure out how to access the map, replace the keys with strings. `dump mymap.get("foo")` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fully qualified class name:

```
dump mymap.get(new java.lang.Integer(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the java language allows classes within `java.lang` to be used as though imported, jdb does not.

```
dump mymap.get(new java.lang.Integer(5))
```

should work.